# How can I filter in Excel based on a list of specific numbers?

Tags: windows, windows-10, microsoft-excel-2010

I need to filter an Excel worksheet based on a specific list of numbers. The data is varied in terms of date and time and other parameters but each record has a specific serial number. That serial number can appear multiple times on different records. How can I filter based on a list of specific serial numbers?

I tried making a custom list under Advanced options but to no avail.

Comment: Select all the cells on your table, and go to Data tab, and Create Table. Then click on your serial number **header**, this will sort the table based on that header. Is this what you're looking for? (I'm using 2016 so I don't remember the buttons for 2010)

Comment: Sorry, I said sort but in reality I'm trying to view only certain records based on a list of specific serial numbers. The table is already sorted by serial number but I would like to only see entries based on the given list of serial numbers

Answer (score 0):

You want to filter unique values.

1. Select the range
2. On the **Data** tab, in the **Sort and Filter** group, click **Filter**.

   [image: Sort and Filter]
3. This will add a filter header to your cell range (see the drop down button).

   [image: Filter Header]
4. Click on the arrow button, and you can search for a value, or filter the shown data to the values you checked.